# Change word emphasis in a sentence with Azure Text-To-Speech SSML

Tags: azure, text-to-speech

I want to change the emphasis to a different word and SSML supports the `<emphasis>` element, but it isn't listed in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup?tabs=csharp). It was ignored when I added it to the SSML markup.
It seems like you could use the prosody-element to change the emphasis.

Update: It looks like the following prosody element results in a similar output than the `<emphasis>` element. The pitch is raised in this case by 30% for the word that has to be emphasised:

```
This is a <prosody pitch="+30.00%">Test</prosody>
```

May be there are other suggestions on how to best emulate emphasis on a word.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a short break before the emphasized word(s) seems to increase the importance. Around 70-200ms seems to be nice.

Also, I tend to slow the rate instead of increasing the pitch.

`This is a <break time="100ms"/><prosody rate="-10.00%">test</prosody>`

Answer (score 0):

`<emphasis>` is now a supported element (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup?tabs=csharp#adjust-emphasis). Currently it is only supported for some English voices however.